# How to call a method in controller with parameter from console command

Tags: php, laravel, controller, command

i want to call a method with parameter request in a controller.
is it possible to call it from console command?
i do it like this :

```
$callwithdraw = Request::create('/api/withdraw','POST',$request);
$response = Route::dispatch($callwithdraw);
```

but it doesn't work. anybody can help?

Comment: Welcome. Create an [artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan#writing-commands) that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `callAction` to call action method.

```php
$request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request($datas);
$controller = app()->make(MyController::class);
$Response = $controller->callAction('ActionName',[$request]);
```